# Communities and Community Cloud?

Tags: community

Are the communities and Community Cloud same?
I bit confused when I see the community is a feature needs to be enabled, then creating domain, branding etc., and accessible using community specific licenses. 
Then what does Community Cloud product denotes? Can anyone please provide a clarity on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Salesforce [Community Cloud](https://www.salesforce.com/products/community-cloud/overview/) is the overall term for the communities products and licence types.

There are several types of community possible for different use cases:

- Customer communities
- Partner communities
- Employee apps and community

Communities cloud [pricing and editions information](https://www.salesforce.com/products/community-cloud/pricing/)